# Xamarin Forms and Asp.Net Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin.forms

I have been following a youtube tutorial on connecting my a xamarin forms app to an asp.net web api. Unfortunately my Listview is not getting populated by data from the api.

The Xamarin forms app has the following Files:

**RestClient.cs**

```
public class RestClient<T>    {
         private const string WebServiceUrl = "http://localhost:49864/api/Oppotunities/";

         public async Task<List<T>> GetAsync()
         {
             var httpClient = new HttpClient();

             var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(WebServiceUrl);

             var OppotunityList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);

             return OppotunityList ;
         } }
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
 public MainViewModel()
           {
               InitializeDataAsync();

           }

           private async Task InitializeDataAsync()
           {
               var oppotunitiesServices = new OppotunitiesServices();
               OppotunitiesList = await oppotunitiesServices.GetOppotunitiesAsync();

           }
```

**OppotunityServices.cs**

```
public class OppotunitiesServices
    {
        public async Task<List<Oppotunity>> GetOppotunitiesAsync()
        {


            RestClient<Oppotunity> restClient = new RestClient<Oppotunity >();
            var oppotunitiesList =  await restClient.GetAsync();


            return oppotunitiesList;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you using an emulator by any change? If so, you should not use localhost to connect to your environment

Comment: Yes. Am using an emulator. Pardon. What can I use please

Comment: use the actual ip address of the machine your web service is running on.
like http:// 192.168.0.101:49864/api/Oppotunities/

Answer (score 0):

If you are debugging from an emulator, you should not use `localhost` to reach your development machine. You have to use the IP address or your running service.

You can test IP addresses directly from the browser of your emulator so you don't waste time starting/stopping your app to debug this...

Hope it helps

Comment: Am still having trouble with testing my web API using the IP Address. When i run the web API service that is currently hosted on the localhost as well:

Comment: Am having a hard one testing my IP address. Previously i was running the web api (which am running locally) then type http://localhost:49864/api/Oppotunities/ on my browser and i would it. Now i replaced my localhost with 169.254.216.197/16 which is the IPV4 address under network name Ethernet and the browser is returning an error "The site cant be reached". Am i testing the wrong way?